# Preventing users from destroying their own questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, review

I recently came accross this question:

[Loops and arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412196/java-homework-loops-and-arrays)

I rolled back the changes, from the 11th version. I was wondering how that edit got through. It's clear to me that removing 90% of the question is almost like destroying the question itself.

It's hard to say why the user wanted to "delete" everything in his own question. I could say that it might be to prevent their teacher from googling the homework and finding his answer.

Shouldn't there be a way to detect these kind of edits and send them to the review queue? Did it get reviewed by someone?

Similar reported situations in comment

- [Haskell - response code of simpleHTTP method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890078/haskell-response-code-of-simplehttp-method)
- [Exceptions and File I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036671/exceptions-and-file-i-o)
- [PHP Session and Cookie Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506061/php-session-and-cookie-issues)
- [going through a text file and listing how many words start with a... b.... c.... d... etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618637/going-through-a-text-file-and-listing-how-many-words-start-with-a-b-c)

Comment: Autoflag for large edits seems like a good idea

Comment: The user can't destroy it anymore. Seems like (s)he ragequit. (Nevermind, it's really old. The OP probably got auto-deleted with time.)

Comment: Something like that but I believed it was already there. @Mysticial even if he quitted, he can create a new account and do the same thing in the future.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix If it's a new account, you can't destroy other people's content without enough rep. Unless of course you're referring to asking more questions just to vandalize them.

Comment: I also had to do that on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21036671/revisions). Some also think that just because their problem is solved they can take most of the code away and just say `SOLVED`.

Comment: @Mysticial yeah i mean him and anybody that could do something like that...

Comment: @hichris123 whoa just looked at the last edit and he left "thanks"...

Comment: @JanDvorak: I've recently seen another user do this on another site with *all three* of their questions.  An autoflag would be good as only a moderator can prevent these destructions.

Comment: You didn't pick a great example.  That question is unlikely to help anyone else, and the OP has long since left town.  Nor the second one, which is also a homework question.

Comment: This happened to me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890078/haskell-response-code-of-simplehttp-method, which wasn't obviously a homework question. When the poster posted a followup question and implied he might do the same, I flagged it for moderator attention and the previous deletion was rolled back. One slight difference was that the poster included their code only on an external pastebin, but I edited it into the question in line with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174302/policy-on-inserting-ops-code-into-his-question/174303

Comment: @RobertHarvey blame me for bad example if you want. It's just impossible to know it's happening until you sees it. I'd try to search better example if we had a history change search engine.

Comment: [In this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506061/php-session-and-cookie-issues), the user removed everything and "moved on" to create a new (duplicate) post.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618637/going-through-a-text-file-and-listing-how-many-words-start-with-a-b-c) where the OP's *obvious* attempt at vandalism was rolled back, but he then went with a second tack - removing just enough detail that it got closed with "unclear what you're asking".  So be aware that users intent on vandalizing their own posts are going to be creative about doing so.

Answer (score 4):

This is already handled, for the most part.

1. User defaces question.
2. It gets bumped to the front page
3. Post is downvoted and flagged
4. Post is rolled back, either by a user with edit privileges, or by a mod.
5. Profit!

Comment: But it took more than two years before the post was rolled back.

Comment: You mean the Java Homework one?  Meh.  Questions that are useful to others will get the necessary attention to insure that they are not defaced.

Comment: @RobertHarvey how can you prove that, it's happening completely randomly